# Watch Git Repositories in a docker volume

Tags: git, docker, webhooks, watch, mirroring

I have a setup of a simple http server that serves the content of a directory, running in docker.
The content of the directory is a static web page, that is versioned with git. When changes happen to the site the remote repository is updated.

How can the cloned repository be updated automatically, when the remote repository is updated. Either the cloned repository watches for changes or the remote sends some hook. Or is there some mirroring mechanism for git repositories?

Is something like [Watchtower](https://containrrr.dev/watchtower/) but for git repositories in volumes instead of docker images available?

Comment: Usually I'd do stuff like that in your CI/CD tool. That might be slightly overkill if this is literally all you want to do (and I'm sure there are simpler solutions for this step), but havinga CI/CD tool is a good idea whenever you are doing anything involving git anyway ... In something like Jenkins this is a trivial build with a single git push command.

Comment: @JoachimSauer A CI is already involved in building the webpage (the page sources are on GitHub and built with Jekyll in GitHub Actions) and push it to the gh-pages branch. But I serve the actual page from my own server/docker host under my domain. So the CI has no access to my server, and should not get direct access to it, except for maybe a hook.

Comment: Github action are meant for this. But you don't want Github to have access to your docker-container, which is understandable. 
Why not put a very very small Public API in the middle. Github signals the API, the API (your API) gives a signal to Docker Container, the Docker Container checks if there is indeed a new version and starts processing when there's indeed a new version.

Comment: That sounds like good idea, the API would be the hook/webhook in this case. The container is only able to server the page as it is. So I would need another container in between that pulls the repository or a script that is directly attached to the webhook.
My question mostly is, does a solution for that setup exist already, alternatively what is the best practice.